# Discord.js Problem when deploying to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, discord.js

I'm trying to deploy my discord.js bot to Heroku but I'm having trouble setting it up!

Hopefully someone can help!
I've displayed the logs from heroku and my package.json file too

***Heroku Logs***

```
2022-01-04T19:12:46.351429+00:00 app[worker.1]: /app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/APIRequest.js:34

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351447+00:00 app[worker.1]:     agent ??= new https.Agent({ ...this.client.options.http.agent, keepAlive: true });

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351448+00:00 app[worker.1]:           ^^^

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351448+00:00 app[worker.1]: 

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351448+00:00 app[worker.1]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '??='

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351448+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:16)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351449+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1049:27)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351449+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351449+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351450+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351451+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RESTManager.js:5:20)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351451+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)

2022-01-04T19:12:46.351451+00:00 app[worker.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
```

***Package.json***

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^13.5.0"
  },
  "name": "amaya-nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "Main.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node Main.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/Citrom67/Amaya-NodeJs.git"
  },
  "author": "Citrom, discord: Cit#7196",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/Citrom67/Amaya-NodeJs/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/Citrom67/Amaya-NodeJs",
  "description": "Discord bot for everyday use",
  "keywords": [ ]
}
```

Any Help is much appreciated! I'm just pretty much lost here since I never did anything like this before. Locally the bot works without a single issue so I don't understand how can it have problem with syntax in discord.js on there! But maybe I just misunderstand it somehow

Comment: Update node on heroku

Comment: uhm, how I do I do that? Do I use in Heroku CLI and also tried finding a newer buildpack but I didn't

Comment: It did fix it! I probably would have been searching for the fix for hours. 
Thank you